# Android Fabric crashlytics causing app crash

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-multidex, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am getting a strange crash due to Fabric Crashlytics.
I am using fabric's crashlytics. But When I run app on S5 5.0 API 21, it crashes the whole application.

See the report below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore;
                                                                    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29)
                                                                    at com.projectname.application.AppData.onCreate(AppData.java:162)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5010)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename-here-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29) 
                                                                    at com.packagename--here.application.AppData.onCreate(AppData.java:162) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5010) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 14 more
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
        maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



apply plugin: 'android-apt'
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "--package--name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 23
        versionName "2.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {


        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    // retrofit, gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.0.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
    // Progress loader
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    //Stetho debug
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    //Stetho OkHttp3
    //compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.16.1')
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    // image picker
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    // instabug
    compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:3+'
    compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:WaveSwipeRefreshLayout:1.6'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.borjabravo:readmoretextview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile project(':versioninfo')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

App is crashing whenever launched.
I have also tried multidex but still there is some issue.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of errors are usually related to the MultiDex usage

take a look at your code and verify that (especially point 2):

1) you have added the multidex support to your app:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

2) You have set your application as a MultiDex Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    // Your application implementation here
}
```

3) you have added multiDexEnabled true setting to your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    // Other settings here
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```